# Sending Android app id in HTTP referrer header

Tags: android, http-headers

I thought I had read somewhere a while ago that Android apps send their id in HTTP requests made from within the app.

I seemed to remember that the id was sent as the HTTP referrer.

I cannot, however, find any mention of this anywhere now.

Did I dream it, or is the id sent somewhere else?

(I understand the unreliability and spoofability of the HTTP referrer header)

Is there any other way to identify which app is making a request to an HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is generic or for all http requests.
I think following link can help you

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/

Comment: On top of it usually when a link is clicked and the app wants link server to know that it has been sent from a particular app then you can add header as referrer and id as your app is